# Does You Android drains battery after system update?

Tags: updates, battery-life, system

I've recently received 2 updates for my Samsung Galasy S5 (SM-G900F) Android 5.0 
There was security patch 2015-05-01, and some other update.

I can not prove that, but my **battery drains like 3x faster** than before updates, and **phone is visibly slower**. It may be some stuff in my system, but for now I blame the update.

Making it more wired: how could we check, if the producer does not 'break' it's own system (by making it slower, drain battery faster) to switch to a new phone?

Any suggestion on how to track the battery-draining/processor-heavy tasks, or a nice Cyanogen for my phone? It's still under warranty, so I'd prefer not to switch to CM yet.

Comment: The second part of the question is off-topic, but I'll suggest you to switch to CM and screw the warranty. What Android version number do you have now?

Comment: As for the other part, highly recommended reading: our [battery-life tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/battery-life/info) ;)

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Mask Salesman kernel: 3.4.0-5508620
dpi@SWHD4018 #1 (9th may)
with SE for android: SEPF_SM-G900F_5.0-1_0051 (20th May)

Answer (score 0):

I did wipe the phone to factory setup, and carefully restore selected applications.
Seems to work for now, but this is terrible update system!